# Group By equal data inside the column aggregated by arrays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset with three columns and I need to group by but keeping the "arrays" with small groups ordered by data:

[image: Original Dataset]

Expected output:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, most easily solved with the difference of row numbers:

```
select type, count(*), min(date_status), max(date_status)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date_status) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by date_status) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
group by type, (seqnum - seqnum_t)
order by min(date_status);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  I find that if someone looks at the results of the subquery, that person will usually see how the difference of the two row number columns identifies groups of adjacent `type`s.